# Having trouble setting a css style for a font-awesome icon whenever it has focus

Tags: css

For the following element, I'm trying to add a css style on a font-awesome icon whenever it receives focus

```
<span class="fa fa-circle" tabindex="0" role="button"></span>
```

I've tried adding the following:

```
.fa fa-circle:focus {

background-color : yellow;

}
```

But the style does not change when I keyboard tab into the element. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Firstly, the selector is wrong (check the answer posted). Second, are you trying to change the background of the element (or) the fill of the circle?

Comment: im trying to add a glow but kept it simple concept wise with what im trying to accomplish

Comment: Ok then change the selector as mentioned in the answer that has been posted.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.fa.fa-circle` instead of `.fa fa-circle`

if it wont work then change the style like this `background-color : yellow !important;`

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/JfGVE/1405/
 Please check fiddle.No need of using `.fa`.

Answer (score 0):

your selector is wrong because `.fa fa-circle:focus` this means that select fa-circle class within fa class. try this css code:

```
.fa, .fa-circle:focus {
background-color:yellow;
}
```